# Yii ActiveRecord cannot define static variable

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, static

I am trying to delcare a static variable within my model in Yii.

Like this

```
class ActiveServices extends MyActiveRecord
{
    public static $periodStr = array(1=>"1 WEEK",
                                     2=>"4 WEEK",
                                     3=>"1 MONTH",
                                     4=>"3 MONTH",
                                     5=>"6 MONTH",
                                     6=>"1 YEAR",
                                    );

    public $periodStrTest = array(1=>"1 WEEK",
                                     2=>"4 WEEK",
                                     3=>"1 MONTH",
                                     4=>"3 MONTH",
                                     5=>"6 MONTH",
                                     6=>"1 YEAR",
                                    );
```

so when i call

```
print_r(ActiveServices::periodStr);
```

i get

> Property "ActiveServices.periodStr" is not defined.

if i call 
    print_r(ActiveServices::periodStrTest);

it works.

Am i missing something simple here?

Regards

Update:

I did try with "protected static" first

Update:

Here is the code for MyActiveRecord

```
<?php
/**
 * This is the custom parent calss for all models
 *
 * This will contain default behaviors
 */


class MyActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @run functions in behaviours file
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
        'ARAuditTrail'=>
            'application.behaviors.ARAuditTrail',
            );
    }
}

?>
```

and CActiveRecord can be found here [CActiveRecord](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
ActiveServices::$periodStr
```

instead:

```
ActiveServices::periodStr
```

Also you can create static method (I think it's is superfluous):

```
public static function getPeriodStr()
{
    return self::$periodStr;
}
```

And call as: `ActiveServices::getPeriodStr();`.

**UPD:** [PHP doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more details about static properties.

Comment: I tried this and the return was "Property "ActiveServices." is not defined.", This is because im not referencing i believe

Comment: I've tried ``var_dump(ActiveServices::$periodStr);`` in test project, all works fine

Comment: I have posted the extra code. 
I think it is a Yii thing as it should work fine

Comment: I've tried your classes just now, ``var_dump(ActiveServices::$periodStr);`` - print array of your date range to browser, no errors.

Comment: OK, i will try again later.

Comment: I am a tool, I tried the following
- $activeService->$periodStr
- $activeService->periodStr
- ActiveServices::periodStr
- Just not the last one, Many thanks, I How can i reference it from and instance of an object, or is this not how it works?

Comment: You tried wrong variants, you just need use ``ActiveServices::$periodStr``(as my answer), see more details in php doc

Comment: You missed ``$`` after ``ActiveServices::``